# Microsoft Word: create a repeating background image

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I am using Word 2003 but can use a higher version if necessary.  I have a document that I need to embed an image onto at a specific position on every page.

I see an option for adding a background image but I see no option to display the image only once per page at a specific position.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the page's Header and Footer and embed it in that view.

It doesn't have to be in the same region of the page as either the header or footer, but if you associate it that way, it will repeat on each page.

Comment: Fourteen years later, my Office 97 software support training is still relevant. I don't know if that's good or frightening.

Answer (score 0):

I used the (PNG) image as a texture and it repeated just fine in Office 2010.

Comment: this is not an answer.